# A list string a string index?

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm sure this is a thing that can be done, well I think so. I want something similar to a list of, but instead of an index of numbers for the index it has strings as the index. What I want to be able to do is store a list of names which then have values so for example:

```
Index: "Bill", Value: 34234
Index: "Hagrid", Value: 4523445
```

and so on.

I could of course just build a custom class, then have a list of that class, but I want to be able to do *.contains on the list, which you can't do with custom classes, you would have to instead loop through the list of and check each item if it matches. I more or less asking if something like the above exists in vb.net, I could of sworn I've seen something like it somewhere.

I run into this problem a lot and varies a lot, and I dont want to have to create 10 tiny little classes just for storing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good use of `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`

You can store what you want like so:

```
Dim _dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
_dict.Add("Bill", 34234)
```

and so on.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of, I'll mark the answer in 7 minutes ha. I had read of these some years ago so I knew something existed that I needed. This will be really handy now that I think about it.

Comment: Your alternative to create a custom class is also a good idea as you could also implement your own equality comparer etc but this is just faster!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
myDict.Add("Bill", 34234)
myDict.Add("Hagrid", 4523445)
```